# Save data by kendo ui and java servlet

Tags: java, jquery, mysql, kendo-ui

Can anybody tell me how to save data by kendo ui and java servlet. That means i have design html fields like Student ID, Student name and want to save it using kendo ui framework and java servlet and return json formatted data after execute my insert query from java servlet.Please consider i am very new to java.

Here is my html

```
<div id="PaymentMasterDetailsDiv" >

                <ul>
                    <li>

                        <label for="User" class="required lbl widthSize15_per">User:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtUser" name="User" class="" maxlength="50" value="123" placeholder="Pleaes Select Payment Id" required validationmessage="Please enter Payment Id" />

                    </li>
                    <li>

                        <label for="Password" class="required lbl widthSize15_per">Password:</label>
                        <input type="text" id="txtPassword" name="Password" class="" maxlength="50" value="123" placeholder="Pleaes Select Payment Id" required validationmessage="Please enter Payment Id" />

                    </li>
                    </ul>
                     <button id="btnSave" class="k-button" type="button" >Save</button>
                   </div>
```

And here is my .js to call my .java

```
SaveCommonInformation: function () {

            var objBranchInfo = 0;
            var serviceUrl = "/api/LoginController";

            jQuery.ajax({
                url: serviceUrl,
               // data: jsonParam,
                type: "POST",
                processData: true,
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                success: onSuccess,
                error: onFailed
            });

        function onSuccess(jsonData) {
            if (jsonData == "Success") {

                alert("Success");
            }
            else if (jsonData == "Common Already Exist") {
                  alert();

            }
            else {
                  alert("Exist");
            }
        }

        function onFailed(error) {
            alert("Error");
        }
    }
```

and this is my .java

```
@WebServlet("/LoginController")
public class LoginController extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public LoginController() {
    super();

}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {



}
```

}

but i can't understand how actually connect to database and insert to database something and also return "Success" or "Common Already Exist" in json formate

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask a question here. Did you try anything so far to solve your problem? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as a start.

Comment: Sorry i missed to share my try! now i shared what i was try but as i am a very beginner so i can't try much more.

Comment: Are there have anyone to let me clear!